# Ansible: count the elements and use in conditional check

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a playbook, which I use for key: value definitions, like this:

```
x_interfaces:
  - eno1
  - eno2
```

And in another playbook (which includes that one, I would like to make a conditional check, like this:

```
- name: debug message
  debug:
    msg: There is more then 1 interface in the machine
  when: x_interfaces|length > '1'
```

But it does not work. I get this error message:

```
The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if x_interfaces|length > '1' %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

What am I doing wrong? If I use `x_interfaces|int > '1'` it will also fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`length` returns a integer. `'1'` is a string.  As the error message states the greater then comparison can't perform an operation between a string and an  integer.

For this to work you simply need to change `'1'` to `1`. You are now comparing an integer to an integer.

```
- name: debug message
  debug:
   msg: There is more then 1 interface in the machine
  when: x_interfaces|length > 1
```